# Doctrine and Symfony2 multiple manytomany references

Tags: php, orm, symfony, doctrine

Here's my problem. I have a couple of entites in my bundle. I'm trying to make a bundle to manage movies. However, in several cases Actors can also be Directors and vice versa. So I've named them as "Artists". And then, at each Movie, in the Movie entity, I want to assign a couple of "Artists" as Directors, a couple as Actors and a couple as Screenplay/Writers. However, I'm unable to reference the Artist entity multiple times with a ManyToMany relationship. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="movies")
 */
class Movie
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artist", inversedBy="movies")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $actors;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artist", inversedBy="movies")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $directors;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artist", inversedBy="movies")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $writers;
```

How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another class to represent the roles of people in a movie.

```
class MovieRole 
{

    // many-to-one with Movie
    protected $movie;

    // many-to-one with Artist
    protected $artist;

    // string, role of the artist
    protected $role;

}
```

Update:

So with this way, your entites becomes like this:

Movie:

```
class Movie 
{

    protected $id;

    protected $name;

}
```

Artist:

```
class Artist 
{

    protected $id;

    protected $name;

}
```

The artist entity and the movie entity doesn't know anything about each other, the `MovieRole` entity joins the two of them.

When you add a director to film, you persist a `MovieRole` entity, with the relevant movie entity, artist entity and 'director' as a role. If you want to give an artist another role, persist another `MovieRole` entity with the same movie and artist, and write the role. Or if you want to add another director, persist another `MovieRole` entity with the same movie, the new director and 'director' as a role.

When you want to find the director of a movie, query the `MovieRole` entity with movie and role as parameters. Or if you want to find all the roles of an artist, query the `MovieRole` entity, with artist as the parameter.

Comment: Why the many-to-one? What if an actor has multiple roles in a movie (i.e. directing it and acting in it at the same time)? I believe some actors have done this. It would be a manytomany then???

Comment: This is not the movie entity. This is the entity used to join two entities, like the one doctrine generates when you use many-to-many. With this way, you have a movie entity, a role entity, and this entity to join them. When you want to add an artist to movie, you persist this entity (MovieRole) adding the relevant movie, artist and roles. The movie entity and role entity is unaware of each other, only this table makes the connection between them. This way, you can add an artist to same movie as much as you want.

Comment: Why the many to one then? Because any artist can have a role, but a role is held by only one artist? Am I getting this correctly?